# TypeScript - Setting "strict: true" seems to have the opposite effect?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I'm new to TypeScript and, perhaps, I'm misunderstanding some of its settings, but I came across some confusing behaviour. I have the following `tsconfig.json` (minimum settings to reproduce the issue):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "esnext"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

One of my modules contains this function (simplified, keeping the relevant code):

```
// A simple dictionary type
interface IDictionary<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

function get_value_from_key(key: string): string {
    const key_values: IDictionary<string> = {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2',
        'key3': 'value3',
    }
    return key_values[key] ?? false;
}
```

If I run `tsc`, I get the following (expected) error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'string | false' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'string'.

170     return key_values[key] ?? false;
```

If I run `tsc --strict`, or add `"strict": true` to file `tsconfig.json`, I don't get any error. My understanding was that, with `strict`, the type checking would be stricter. Instead, it seems looser.

Clearly, I'm missing something here. Is this the expected behaviour, or perhaps I configured TypeScript incorrectly?

**Update**
I copied the example in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and I found out what setting triggers the error:

1. When `strictNullChecks` is **enabled**, no error is displayed.
2. When `strictNullChecks` is **disabled**, then the last row in the function throws an error.

I will have to read again about `strictNullChecks`, as my understanding was that it would work the opposite way.

Comment: Really? Because I get "Type `string` cannot be used to index type (type of `key_values`)". If, for some reason, you have `noImplicitAny` disabled (which should be enabled by default with `--strict`, then `key_values[key]` will be implicitly `any`, so `key_values[key] ?? false` will be `any`, which can be cast to `string`.

Comment: My apologies, it looks like I oversimplified my example, when I extracted it from the main code base. The list of values is actually declared as a dictionary type, which allows to use a string as a key. I'm going to update the code with the correct example.